# Go MIDI portmidi installation

Tags: go, wrapper, midi

I'm new in Go. I want to use PortMidi wrapper for Go, trying to use this:
[Go PortMidi](https://github.com/rakyll/portmidi)

When using:

```
go get github.com/rakyll/portmidi
```

I've got:

```
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/github.com/rakyll/portmidi/_obj/portmidi.cgo2.o: undefined reference to symbol 'Pt_Start'
/usr/lib/libporttime.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Tried to search something about:

```
DSO missing from command line
```

And:

```
undefined reference to symbol 'Pt_Start'
```

But found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repaired it.

Installing libportmidi0 from official repo is bad idea. Need to compile it, for example from:

[PortMIDI source download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portmedia/files/portmidi/217/portmidi-src-217.zip/download)

All the instructions how to compile it in directory *pm_linux*.

Comment: Do you know why the official repo version doesn't work?

Comment: Don't know why. But when downloading from repo, it has older version (1:200-0ubuntu3, which propably means v. 200). When downloading from official developer site, it has proper version (v. 217)

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic library of libportmidi is missing.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libportmidi0
```

That should fix it if you're on a debian/ubuntu system. If the library is not available on your linux system search your can still get the library source and compile it yourself.

Comment: I had it. Reinstallation changes nothing.